How to debug dynamics in Gazebo Ignition Harmonic
I've been working on a personal project for a couple of days. I've the entire robot in SDF inside Gazebo Ignition and now I'm trying to use the plugin DiffDrive to move around the world. When I tried to move in angular or linear velocity I see some strange movements. My question is...

Is there any tool or plugin for debug the physics and see where is the problem?

